# Prove that $\mathrm{in}_<(fg)=\mathrm{in}_<(f)\mathrm{in}_<(g)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Fix a term order $<$.
>
> Let $f,g \in S=K[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$
>
> Prove that $\mathrm{in}_<(fg)=\mathrm{in}_<(f)\mathrm{in}_<(g)$

Let $\mathrm{in}_<(f)=x^a$ and $\mathrm{in}_<(g)=x^b$. I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: $in_<(I)=\{in_<(f) | f \in I\}$

Comment: Don't know if there is a simpler example than [this](https://books.google.ro/books?id=dpvw9aW9MigC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=%22LT(I)2%22+leading&source=bl&ots=LzNfMthmgJ&sig=_0f5n3P5Iw_3GaB4meB2fwX1Fps&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDxYLO4MXTAhXDC5oKHTN7DykQ6AEIITAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: What is $\text{in}_>(I)$?  What is $\text{in}_<(I)$?  What is $S$?  What are $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I found http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahmki/acyr2.pdf but I do not understand the part since we have $g: \ldots$

Comment: If you notice that $m_1>m_2$ and $n_1> n_2$ implies $m_1n_1>m_2n_2$ for monomials then you are done.

Comment: Btw, I didn't appreciate the radical way you edited the question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought proving the parts about ideals $I,J$ proved my original question - but it turns out it's the other way. 

Why is $m_1>m_2$ and same for n. The implication I understand but why are we done?

Comment: Since $f$ and $g$ are sums of monomials and their product $fg$ is a sum of products of monomials.